# Why does this code even compile?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Question: 
Why does the below code (not written by me) even compile ?
I mean apart from the fact that option strict is off and option infer is on...

```
If Not actdate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday And Not actdate.DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
...
End If
```

<del>**Edit:**

Just for those not fluent in VB, it's oviously the same as:</del>

```
if (!(actdate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) & !actdate.DayOfWeek.Sunday) {
...
}
```

<del>which basically answers the question already, since the thing to remember is that the VB-`AND` is actually a bitwise and.</del>

Comment: That's the difference between logical and bitwise operation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx

Comment: Then why does `If 1 = 1 And "hi" Then ...` also compile?  It'll give you a runtime exception, but still compiles.

Comment: @JefferyKhan: Probably because `Option Strict` is off.

Comment: @SLaks Sweet, I didn't know that option existed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The accepted answer is not correct, operator precedence in VB.NET ensures that the logical version of And operator is used, same one as AndAlso.  Both the left-hand and right-hand operands are of type Boolean thanks to the Not operators being used.  Precedence in VB.NET is relational > Not > And.  In C# it is ! > relational > &.  Or to put it another way, you don't need parentheses in VB.NET like you do in C#.

The Not operator in Visual Basic accepts a Boolean or numeric expression.  Just like in C#, an enum value is implicitly convertable to an integral value type that matches the Enum's base type.  Integer in this case.  A numeric value of 0 converts to False.  Since DayOfWeek.Sunday's underlying value is 0, the Not expression always produces True.

So this is acceptable syntax.  You do however get a warning for this code, very similar to the error you get in C#:

> warning BC42025: Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

Produced by the Sunday enum member used in the actdate.DayOfWeek property expression.  That is certainly a code smell.  Short from not ignoring warnings, you can turn that warning into an error.  Project + Properties, Compile tab, Warning configuration section.  Change the "Instance variable accesses shared member" setting from Warning to Error.

Comment: Classic. I think it should do A. Oh no, actually it does B. Oh wait, it really does C. And again wrong, what it ultimately does is B ;)